# PHP - Preg_match_all - Regular Expression - help

Tags: php, tags, preg-match-all

i've been working on this question since yesterday, i have the following code..

```
 <?php
    /* 
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    echo "evalia:".$param[1]."<br>";
    $i=0;
    while($i<100)
      $i++;
    ?>
    cvbcbcbcvb
    <?php
    echo "asdsad";
    for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
    {
       echo $i;
    }
    ?>
```

### and i need to get what is inside the  tag.... can anyone help me?

ok i explained myself really badly....
in another page i use file_get_contents to get this code ( this is only a test page nothing more) ... i can't use include for a serious reason so i need to use eval on the code inside the php tag so what i really need is the regular expression to grab everything inside the  tag..

Comment: what tag? can you be more specific?

Comment: What tag? also `$i=0;white($i<100) $i++;` is a bit redundant `$i=100` is equivalent, but then you don't do anything with $i after that?

Comment: I don't see `preg_match_all()` in your code.

Comment: ok i explained myself really badly.... in another page i use file_get_contents to get this code ( this is only a test page nothing more) ... i can't use include for a serious reason so i need to use eval on the code inside the php tag so what i really need is the regular expression to grab everything inside the tag..

Comment: Why do you need to grab everything from php tag? Why you can't eval all the file together with php tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("|<\?php(.*?)\?>|msU", $string, $match);
eval($match[1]);
```

is it your answer?

Comment: so you don't have any <?php ?> tags in your file/variable

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem that you use double quotes. Try single quotes.

Comment: i checked and there is(an echo on the $string)..... i don't know why isn't working but the code i'm using as example is the code above... i already thought about the solution you proposed but as i already told return an empty array..

Answer (score 1):

Im my opinion you don't need to extarct the code from php tags. You can just eval all the content of the file:

```
eval(" ?>$file_content<?php ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use include which is actually quite like eval:

```
include('data:text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($file_content));
```

See [`data://`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) for details about the data: (» RFC 2397) stream wrapper.

See as well [Karolis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956478/php-preg-match-all-regular-expression-help/6957043#6957043).

Comment: Nice. Didn't know PHP supports this protocol for inclusion.

Comment: @Karolis: added a link, just in case.